# Meaning of the numbers on the side of paragraphs in the Ada Reference Manual

Tags: ada

The Reference Manual paragraphs have a "side number" (this is how I call them).

For example, in the attached screenshot of the [Reference Manual Introduction](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-0-3.html), the first "side numbers" are `1`, `2`, `3/3`, `4/1`, `5/3`, `6/3` ,`7`.

What is the meaning of the number **after** the slash sign ?

I could not find the explanation in http://www.ada-auth.org.

[image]

Comment: So far as I know, it indicates the number of revisions: `1` is the zeroth revision (!), `6/3` is the third revision.
It _probably_ only increments at an official release, i.e. not at successive drafts.

Comment: These are _paragraph numbers_. A slash followed by a number indicates which revision of the language introduced the current wording: AIUI, no slash indicates ISO/IEC 8652:1995; 1 indicates ISO/IEC 8652:1995 + TC1; 2, ISO/IEC 8652:2007 (which is actually ISO/IEC 8652:1995 + TC1 +Amendment 1); 3, ISO/IEC 8652:2012. ISO/IEC 8652:1995 was such a significant revision to ANSI/MIL-STD-1815A (1983) that apparently no paragraphs are attributed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the final paragraph of the Introduction of the latest Ada Reference Manual: [www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-0-2.html#p73](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-0-2.html#p73)

Copy-paste:

Using this version of the Ada Reference Manual

72/5
This document has been revised with the corrections specified in Technical Corrigendum 1 for Ada 2012 (which corresponds to ISO/IEC 8652:2012/COR.1:2016) and other changes specifically for Ada 2022. In addition, a variety of editorial errors have been corrected.

73/5
Changes to the original 1995 version of the Ada Reference Manual can be identified by the version number following the paragraph number. Paragraphs with a version number of /1 were changed by Technical Corrigendum 1 for Ada 95 or were editorial corrections at that time, while paragraphs with a version number of /2 were changed by Amendment 1 or were more recent editorial corrections, and paragraphs with a version number of /3 were changed by the 2012 edition of the Reference Manual or were still more recent editorial corrections. Paragraphs with a version number of /4 are changed by Technical Corrigendum 1 for Ada 2012 or were editorial corrections at that time. Paragraphs with a version number of /5 are changes or editorial corrections for Ada 2022. Paragraphs not so marked are unchanged since the original 1995 edition of the Ada Reference Manual, and have the same paragraph numbers as in that edition. In addition, some versions of this document include revision bars near the paragraph numbers. Where paragraphs are inserted, the paragraph numbers are of the form pp.nn, where pp is the number of the preceding paragraph, and nn is an insertion number. For instance, the first paragraph inserted after paragraph 8 is numbered 8.1, the second paragraph inserted is numbered 8.2, and so on. Deleted paragraphs are indicated by the text This paragraph was deleted. Deleted paragraphs include empty paragraphs that were numbered in the 1995 edition of the Ada Reference Manual.